# Post different photos to facebook timeline via Graph API but I got some post_id

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, post, photos, timeline

I try to post panoramas to Facebook via Graph API, each time I upload a panorama.

The first time When I uploaded, the result was perfect.
The panorama exist at album named my app name, 
not exist at album named Timeline Photos.
And the panorama will appear in my timeline,
so I can see the 360 photo on Desktop/App facebook.
[panorama](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJJhJ.png)

But when I upload a panorama again, the panorama will add to album named my app name. But at my timeline, those panorama will in the same post, it just like this picture
[panorama](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce6XN.png)

Then I can't see 360 photo anymore.

I test the Instagram app, and I found that I post a photo to facebook via Instagram app, It also upload to 'Instagram photos' album and appear at my timeline. Even if I upload a photo again, at my timeline, those photo are different post.

In my code, I used Graph API to post panorama to facebook.

```
NSString *api = @"https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos";
NSString *token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString];
NSDictionary *param = @{@"message": @"test",
                        @"access_token": token,
                        @"allow_spherical_photo": [NSNumber numberWithBool:true]};
```

Is the api right? 
If it right, what Parameter or setting I miss?

Comment: Both of your screenshots seem to show exactly the same thing.

Comment: sorry, my bad. I had updated.

Comment: Grouping of multiple photo posts made over a certain period of time is something Facebook does automatically, there is little you can do about that.

Comment: But in Instagram app that I post photo to facebook continuous, it's not become grouping post.

Comment: Instagram is owned by Facebook, and as such the official app might be able to do stuff normal 3rd-party apps aren’t.

Comment: oh I forget that Instagram is owned by Facebook. Yes you are right, official might doing something that sdk not support. Thanks your help.